# Samba subfolders not readable

Tags: permissions, samba, directory

My Samba install was working fine, until I decided to organize the many folders into subfolders. Now I can still connect to the Samba share and see the subfolders, but I can't look inside them. Even the subfolders that were fine before can't be opened. Video files in the share folder are able to play.

I have tried many variations of files permissions and ownerships, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
[video]
path = /home/scott/video
comment = No comment
read only = yes
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = yes
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no


drwxr-xr-x  6 scott  scott       24576 Mar 24 14:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 98 scott  scott        4096 Mar 24 14:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x 61 scott  scott        4096 Mar 24 12:49 AtoE/
-rw-r--r--  1 scott  scott  1668731824 Mar 24 02:47 movie1.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 scott  scott  1695138223 Mar 24 02:47 movie2.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 scott  scott          57 Sep  9  2016 .directory
drwxr-xr-x 74 scott  scott       12288 Mar 24 03:55 FtoN/
drwxrwxr-x  2 nobody nobody       4096 Mar 24 14:37 junk/
drwxr-xr-x 87 scott  scott        4096 Mar 24 11:44 OtoZ/
```

Note that the permissions for this folder, which is accessible, are the same as for the subfolders that are not. I tried smbguest as a directory owner as well, and that didn't work.

Comment: Need a few more details here. What exact error message do you get when trying to access a folder? Is this a server you're connecting to from some other device? Have you tried running smbclient on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Turning up the debug level showed that the problem is  [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1675698) in Samba filed yesterday.

Adding `follow symlinks = yes` to each share section in smb.conf resolved the issue.